# ts-node and gulp don't seem to play nicely

Tags: node.js, gulp, ts-node

in my package.json I have
"type": "commonjs"

when I run my script this works :
"start": "ts-node src/index.ts",

gulp complains :
"Cannot use import statement outside a module"
(I'm using import rather than require as not all packages support require).

If I switch the type to "module" in pacakge.json my gulp script runs but then my script complains : TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for .... src\index.ts

Is there a way to configure the two to co-exist? Is it possible to have multiple configs?

Answer (score 0):

Try to config your tsconfig.json in the following way:

```json
{
  "ts-node": {
    // these options are overrides used only by ts-node
    // same as our --compilerOptions flag and our TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS environment variable
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext"
  }
}
```

Check this out, this issue is similar to yours: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/922